# Is there a way to insert the parameter in a WFS-StoredQuery so that it does not have to be assigned

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have a StoredQuery with 4 parameters. If I assign all 4 parameters everything works as expected. This is my StoredQuery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="gemarkungsname_fln_fsn_zae">
    <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fln" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_zae" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_nen" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="EKR_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
            <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
                <fes:And>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fln</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fln}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_zae</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_zae}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_nen</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_nen}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </fes:And>
            </fes:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```

If I assign all 4 parameters everything is fine: For example as in the following URL. This query shows me 1 result.

```
GEOSERVER/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=gemarkungsname_fln_fsn_zae&gemarkungsname=Beetz&fln=6&fsn_zae=97&fsn_nen=1&outputFormat=JSON
```

If I omit a parameter, then nothing is found. Certainly because the `AND` part fails. If I change my example above - I left out the parameter `fsn_nen`, nothing is found:

```
GEOSERVER/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=gemarkungsname_fln_fsn_zae&gemarkungsname=Beetz&fln=6&fsn_zae=97&fsn_nen=1&outputFormat=JSON
```

**Is there a way to insert the parameter in the StoredQuery so that it does not have to be assigned?**